# C++ gcc `floorf` not a member of `std`?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <cmath>

float foo(float x, unsigned int m, float q = 0.0f)
{
    return std::floorf(x * float(m) + q);
}
```

Now when I try to compile this with g++ 5.4.0 and options `-std=c++11` I get an error saying `‘floorf’ is not a member of ‘std’`.

Now it is my understanding that clause 26.8 of the C++11 standard mandates that the standard C++ library header `<cmath>` declare the same set of functions as the standard C library header `<math.h>`, albeit in the namespace `std`; and that clause 1.2 specifies that "C" is to be interpreted as C99; and that clause 7.12.9.2 of the C99 standard mandates that the standard C library header `<math.h>` declare a function `float floorf(float)`.

So by that reasoning `<cmath>` should declare a function `float std::floorf(float)`, which to the best of my knowledge should be a match for my code.

What gives? Am I missing something here?

<strike>*(I know C++11 also defines a `float std::floor(float)`; however, I've recently made the discovery that the `f`-suffixed variants of float functions are generally slightly faster, so I'd prefer to specifically invoke `floorf()`.)*</strike>

Comment: That is odd, it seems to work fine when compiling using clang++ but indeed with g++ it does not seem to work even on the latest version.

Comment: You think I should file a bug report?

Comment: My `libm-2.24.so` does present a `floorf()` call. It's there, so maybe its an omission in the header? Filing a bug report might be a good idea. Meanwhile, for information, can you hack around the problem merely by writing your own, one-line declaration for `floorf()`?

Comment: @ChristophLipka It may be a bug indeed since in the header I think that is being used does not show it as can be seen [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/c_std/cmath#L243), if anything though I doubt you'd get any performance increase by using it since it's already using a builtin floorf anyways, so you might as well just use the normal `std::floor` for now.

Comment: I have no idea how that declaration would have to look like. I do see that `::floorf` seems to exists; but that's also no alternative, as it's not portable (`<cmath>` does not have to provide the functions in the global namespace).

Comment: It's a library issue. Are you on MS Windows?

Comment: Windows subsystem for Linux.

Comment: By "library issue", do you mean "header file issue" or literally "library issue"?

Comment: For reference, I've just filed this on [Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89279)

Comment: The C++11 and C++14 standards didn't list `floorf` in the Table "Header `<cmath>` synopsis",  it was fixed in C++17. A pedantic reading of the standard could conclude that `<cmath>` only has to offer `::floorf` and not `std::floorf`

Comment: By that pedantic reading, GCC would also have to refrain from defining any of the other `f` suffix functions, and yet it provides e.g. `std::ilogbf`. Also, `-std=c++17` gives the same error message.

Comment: Relevant link https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor. Also, "I've recently made the discovery that the f-suffixed variants of float functions are generally slightly faster", that sounds very strange to me.

Comment: Apparently the issue has been known for 2 years, see [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79700) Bugzilla entry.

Comment: For the speed difference, were you measuring with `-O0`? `std::pow` is a function that calls `powf` while `powf` is directly `powf`, so that's slower if you don't inline, but I would expect inlining to get rid of the difference quite easily.

Comment: *Groan!!* Hit me with something blunt and heavy... I think I may actually have kept using `-o3` instead of `-O3`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe that you have indeed found a bug in the header. On my GCC, using the GNU C library (glibc), I can work around by dropping out of `std::` into the global namespace, changing

```
    return std::floorf(x * float(m) + q);
```

to

```
    return ::floorf(x * float(m) + q);
```

The workaround works because `floorf()` belongs to the C standard library, so it has a global symbol in glibc. Since the workaround uses the global symbol, which C++11 allows but does not require to exist, the workaround is nonportable. Nevertheless, for glibc, it appears to work.

The workaround could be made portable, if you wish, by changing `#include <cmath>` to `#include <math.h>` and (as far as I know) dropping all your C-math-library calls into the global namespace. It would still be just a workaround, though.

You may go ahead and report this as a bug at: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/. Moreover, to be taken more seriously by the GCC team, you can link the bug report back here to show that several competent pairs of eyes have already looked at the problem. Meanwhile, nice work.

Comment: "It's not right, but it works." -- well, it is right in the sense that C++11 does allow such a global symbol to exist. It does not mandate it though, so any program making use of this global symbol is non-portable.

Comment: @ChristophLipka it's portable if you include `<math.h>` instead.

Comment: @thb _"in GCC's libc6"_  -- there's no such thing. I assume you mean the GNU C library, but that's more correctly called "glibc" not "libc6" and is not part of GCC. GCC does not provide a C library, it uses the system's existing C library.

Comment: @JonathanWakely <math.h> is technically a C header, included in C++ only for compatibility with the C library. I'll want to avoid relying on that, because it makes things kludgy. Fortunately a portable genuine C++ approach exists, in using the `floor(float)` overload.

Comment: @ChristophLipka, technically it's a C++ header with similar (but not identical) content to the C header of the same name.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Let me rephrase that: Technically it's a (C++ compatible) header for the C standard library. So if I include it, I need to link to the C runtime library, even if all my other code would be fine with just the C++ runtime library. (And yes, I guess on some platforms the C and C++ library may physically be the same entity, but that's beside my point.)

Comment: @ChristophLipka no that's nonsense. The standard requires that `std::floorf` and `::floorf` refer to **the  same function**, so either that one function is defined in the C runtime (e.g. libc or libm) and the C++ runtime will link to that automatically to make the definition available, or it's defined in the C++ runtime (e.g. libstdc++) but either way, it makes no difference which header you include. And the `floor(float)` overload is just going to make a call to `floorf(float)` rather than duplicate the definition, so that still uses the same definition eventually, whether it's in libc or not